# get data from webservice and set it to variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, web-services

I need to get data from webservice url in javascript. i"m getting the response code as 200 but dont get any data from the url.
Following is the code

```
var xmlDoc = null;
url = 'http://localhost:8458/service1.svc/geturl';

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlDoc = new XMLHttpRequest(); //Newer browsers
}
else if (window.ActiveXObject) //IE 5, 6
{
    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

if (xmlDoc) {

    xmlDoc.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlDoc.readyState == 4 && xmlDoc.status === 200) {
                alert(xmlDoc.responseText);
            }

        }
        xmlDoc.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlDoc.send();
```

and the service which i have written returns the string

Comment: what type of data is being returned? JSON? If you use something like Firebug you can see what data is being returned if any.

Comment: the data which is returned is not in json format. it simply returns the url in form of string

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using jQuery for this:

```
var request_url = 'http://localhost:8458/service1.svc/geturl';

$.ajax({
  url: request_url,
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(response){
     // Do something with your response here
     alert(response);
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you included the jQuery library? Is there definitely something at the localhost address?